# how to create a bash script, with alternative of "goto" and "labels"

Tags: bash, batch-jobs

In batch:

```
@echo off
:step1
if exist "file1.txt" (GOTO step2) ELSE (GOTO X)
:step2
if exist "file2.txt" (GOTO Z) ELSE (GOTO Y)

:X
run the script from the beginning and file1.txt and file2.txt are created and the rest of the script is executed
:Y
run the commands to file1.txt and run the rest of the script
:Z
run the commands to file2.txt and run the rest of the script
```

I know "goto" and "labels" don't exist in bash, but what is the alternative to do something similar to the above in bash?

attempt:

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ -e file1.txt ]; then
        echo "file1.txt ok"
            if [ -e file2.txt ]; then
                echo "file2.txt ok"
                alternative to goto label Z
            else
                alternative to goto label Y
            fi
    else
        echo "file1.txt doesn't exist"
        alternative to goto label X
fi
```

PD: rudimentary scripts only for the purpose of conveying the idea

**What does the batch (and should also do the bash) (Important to avoid confusion):**

The full script runs a few commands and creates the files file1.txt and file2.txt. So since the script is very long and can be interrupted at some point, what I want is to start the script from where it was interrupted. This is what verification is for:

- If file1.txt exists (Y), then the script has already created it, and goes on to check if file2.txt (Z) exists (another part of the script).
- If file2.txt exists (Z), it means that the commands start from that point
- If file2.txt (Z) does not exist, but file1.txt (Y) exists, it means that the script was interrupted somewhere between creating file1.txt (Y) and file2.txt (Z), then it starts at file1.txt (Y)
- If neither file1.txt (Y) nor file2.txt (Z) exists then I have to start from the beginning of script (X)

Comment: There's no `goto` in bash. Use functions and structured programming techniques.

Comment: Please explain what do you actually want the control flow to be in your script, as it's hard to understand from your question. Where exactly are labels "start", "a" and "b" located in both examples? Maybe draw a block diagram?

Comment: Don't use `ls file` and then test for exit code. Test right away for file's existence: `if [ -e file1 ]; then ...`

Comment: @raj thanks. update question with your fix

Comment: In your first (batch) example, the control flow is as follows: if `file1` doesn't exist, you run EVERYTHING from the label `start` up to the end of the script (ie. also commands after labels `a` and `b`). If `file1` exists AND `file2` exists, you run only commands after the label `b`. If `file1` exists but `file2` doesn't, you run commands after label `a` AND after label `b`. So it doesn't seem to be what you want, according to descriptions. On the other hand, your second (bash) example seems to be correct, it only lacks `fi` before the second `else`.

Comment: what you describe is exactly what i want in bash. If file1.txt exists, check file2.txt. If file2.txt exists, run commands from file2.txt only. If file2.txt does not exist, run only commands from file1.txt. If file1.txt does not exist, run the entire script. What happens is that since the script is very large and the parts are far from each other, I would like to use something similar to "labels" from windows batch

Comment: But your **batch** example does not do what you describe above. It does something different. If `file1.txt` exists, checks `file2.txt` and if `file2.txt` exists, runs commands for `file2.txt` only - up to this point your description is correct. BUT if `file2.txt` does not exist, your script runs commands for `file1.txt` AND THEN commands for `file2.txt`. And if `file1.txt` doesn't exist, it runs "all script", THEN commands for `file1.txt` AND THEN commands for `file2.txt`. As I already wrote, your **bash** example actually does what you described.

Comment: Your batch example lacks an `:exit` label at the very end and additional `goto exit` commands before labels `:comfile1` and `:comfile2`. With this addition it will behave as you described. But you can also write your batch example completely without `goto`, in the same style as the bash script, by using nested `IF ... THEN (...) ELSE (...)`

Comment: @ilkkachu We are talking about the **batch** example, right? When the `run all script` part finishes, it will just continue to next commands - that is to `run only commands for file1.txt` (because there is no command at that place that tells the script to finish). When that one finishes, it will similarly continue to `run only commands for file2.txt`. See my previous comment - additional `goto` commands need to be introduced to make each of these parts exit and not continue to next commands.

Comment: @raj "BUT if file2.txt does not exist, your script runs commands for file1.txt AND THEN commands for file2.txt. And if file1.txt doesn't exist, it runs" all script ", THEN commands for file1.txt AND THEN commands for file2.txt ". Your analysis is correct. So exactly

Comment: @ajcg To avoid misunderstanding, let's call the `run all script` part X, `run only commands for file1.txt` - Y and `run only commands for file2.txt` - Z. So is this what you want to run parts X, Y and Z if `file1.txt` doesn't exist, parts Y and Z if `file1.txt` exists but `file2.txt` not, and only part Z if both `file1.txt` and `file2.txt` exist?

Comment: @raj I have updated the question including your requirements to avoid confusion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After knowing exactly what your batch script should do, I would start with simplifying it a bit:

```
@echo off
if exist "file1.txt" goto skip_part1
run the script from the beginning and file1.txt and file2.txt are created and the rest of the script is executed
:skip_part1
if exist "file2.txt" goto skip_part2
run the commands to file1.txt and run the rest of the script
:skip_part2
run the commands to file2.txt and run the rest of the script
```

which can be equivalently written as:

```
@echo off
if not exist "file1.txt" (
  run the script from the beginning and file1.txt and file2.txt are created and the rest of the script is executed
)
if not exist "file2.txt" (
  run the commands to file1.txt and run the rest of the script
)
run the commands to file2.txt and run the rest of the script
```

and this can be directly translated to the following bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ ! -e file1.txt ]; then
  run the script from the beginning and file1.txt and file2.txt are created and the rest of the script is executed
fi
if [ ! -e file2.txt ]; then
  run the commands to file1.txt and run the rest of the script
fi
run the commands to file2.txt and run the rest of the script
```

Comment: please check your answer

Comment: @ajcg what do you mean exactly?

Comment: Your script is fine, but the alternative to labels is missing. That's what my question is about

Comment: What do you mean by "alternative to labels is missing"? I don't understand.

Comment: read the question: how to create a bash script, **with alternative of “goto” and “labels”**. This means that the alternatives for :X :Y :Z are missing

Comment: @ajcg As there is no `goto` and labels in bash, you have to construct the script so that neither `goto` nor labels are needed. I tried to create a script that does the same that you wanted, but doesn't use `goto` nor labels. That's what I understand by an "alternative". If you mean something different, please explain what "alternative of `goto` and labels" means to you. :X, :Y and :Z are only labels, so we can't have them in bash script. But the **code** that was between these labels is there.

Comment: The problem is that I cannot break the code into parts as it is too complex. That is the real reason for my question. I need to do the check for the existence of the files and jump to that part of the script.

Comment: The problem is that I cannot break the code into parts as it is too complex. That is the real reason for my question. I need to do the check for the existence of the files and jump to that part of the script.

Comment: @ajcg But in your example the code is broken into parts. The first part is between labels :X and :Y, the second part is between labels :Y and :Z, the third part is between label :Z and the end of the script. These parts are exactly copied to the bash script. If this example does not correspond to real layout of your code, why did you give it? You **cannot jump** to arbitrary part of the code in bash, period. If you use such jumps, you must restructure your code to get rid of them. There is no other possibility.

Comment: I will try to apply your solution. If it does not cause me problems, I accept your answer and select it as correct. Thanks for your support

Comment: @ajcg It's been long considered that [gotos tend to lead to confusing code](https://homepages.cwi.nl/~storm/teaching/reader/Dijkstra68.pdf), so modern programming (and scripting) languages tend to avoid them and use [structured control elements](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Structured_programming) instead. Your original script... looks like a good example of the messes you get with gotos. Rather than trying to translate that mess into an equivalent bash mess, I'd recommend taking the opportunity to clean it up (as in raj's example here).

Comment: @GordonDavisson thanks for your observation and I have taken it into account and applied it. PD: I have made all the requested corrections and I have given all the requested explanations, however, the community marks my question as negative. This site is scary, especially for newbies. You never know what to expect from the community.

Answer (score 2):

The script can be pretty much automatically converted, although it will look strange!
The steps are

1. At the start of the script insert

```
_current_label="_first_state"
main_function(){
case "$_current_label" in
("_first_state")
```

2. At the end of the script append

```
_current_state="_the_end"
return
;;
esac
}
while [ "$current_state" != "_the_end" ] ; do main_function ; done
```

3. Change each `:label` into

```
_current_label="label"
;;
("label")
```

4. Change each `goto skip_part1` into

```
_current_label="skip_part1"
return
```

So your script will look like

```
#!/bin/bash
_current_label="_first_state"
main_function(){
case "$_current_label" in
("_first_state")
_current_label="step1"
;;
("step1")
if [ -e file1.txt ]; then
        echo "file1.txt ok"
        _current_label="step2"
        return
else
        echo "file1.txt doesn't exist"
        _current_label="X"
        return
fi
_current_label="step2"
;;
("step2")
            if [ -e file2.txt ]; then
                echo "file2.txt ok"
                _current_label="Z"
                return
            else
                _current_label="Y"
                return
            fi
           _current_label="X"
;;
("X")
run the script from the beginning and file1.txt and file2.txt are created and the rest of the script is executed
_current_label="Y"
;;
("Y")
run the commands to file1.txt and run the rest of the script
_current_label="Z"
;;
("Z")
run the commands to file2.txt and run the rest of the script
_current_label=""
return
;;
esac
}
while [ "$current_label" != "" ] ; do main_function ; done
```

The idea is that you construct a very simple finite state machine. Each state  is a label in the case statement. In each state you run the code until you encounter a `goto` in the original code, at which point you set the global value `_current_label` and return, or you encounter a label. A loop will then cause the case statement to be run again starting at this new label.

Note the "automatic" translation puts in some code that can never be executed.

This "automatic" translation doesn't handle `call` or `start` statements.

If you have a tool to indent the resulting script I would urge you to run it!

Comment: your response is very good and I appreciate it very much. What I don't understand is why so many are interested in my problem and offer me good solutions, but the community marks the question as negative. thanks anyway

Comment: A recurring theme on this site is the [XYProblem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/905740) and your question may well fit it. My solution answers your question with how to implement goto and labels in bash, whilst @raj provides an answer of how to redesign your code. The fact that you currently have 2 such very different answers suggests that the question may not have been very good.   Perhaps take the tour and earn the "Informed" badge?

Comment: What you say is true. But if I mark your answer as correct, my question will be severely punished with more negative points in retaliation for my behavior. This is how this place is. That is why many prefer not to use it and look for a solution elsewhere

Comment: I am sorry you feel this way. Where should I invest my time instead of stackexchange.com if I want to help people?

Comment: And you have helped me a lot. I am using your solution. But others prefer to spam and mark the question as negative, instead of doing what you do, helping others